# How to Compare current date and user given date?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to compare the current date and the date that set by user in my "cal_set" calendar, i want to accept the date if date is today date or upcoming date else show toast if date is passed.

This is my onDateSet method.

```
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        cal_set.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
        cal_set.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal_set.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        if(cal_set.getTime().after(cal_now.getTime))
        {
            tv_date.setText(new StringBuffer().append(day).append("/").append(month).append("/").append(year));
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select upcoming date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

i am setting date in cal_now when user click on view that calles onDateSet method.

```
    iv_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {   
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            day_now =  Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            month_now = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).get(Calendar.MONTH);
            year_now = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).get(Calendar.YEAR);

            cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();

            showDialog(ID_DATE);
        }
    });

        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch (id) 
    {
        case ID_DATE:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, onDateSetListener, year_now, month_now, day_now);
        default:
            break;
    }

    return null;
}
```

any help please.

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: use before() in place of after()... and change statements inside the method

Comment: Michael if i change condition and statements to opposite its gonna do same thing i think!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem finally, now i let the datepicker get date from user and than i set that date in EditText, when user clicks on submit button i just get strings from edittext and parse them into date format like this:

```
s_date_temp = date_format.parse(et_sdate.getText().toString());
e_date_temp = date_format.parse(et_edate.getText().toString());
```

After that i compare these dates like this:

```
if(s_date_temp.after(e_date_temp))
{
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: The Start Date Must Occur Prior To Th End Date!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can compare `Date` with `compareTo()`. However, in your case, you can use `Calendar` methods `setMaxDate()` and `setMinDate()`.

Comment: Where should i use setMaxDate() and setMinDate(), i have no idea how it can help.

Comment: You can disallow user to select an upcoming date. But, it is another application level design, forget it... You can use `compareTo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "now = new Date();" to get the actual date.
Then to test if the entered date is superior or equal to the actual date, use:
    if (setdate.compareTo(now)>=0) {
    // do your stuff here.
    }

Comment: it gives error here if(cal_now.compareTo(date)>=0) "The method compareTo(Calendar) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (Date)"

Comment: Yes, both arguments need to be a Date. Type "cal_now.getTime().compareTo(date)"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean CompareDates(String strDate1,String strDate2)
{
    try 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(strDate1);
        Date date2 = sdf.parse(strDate2);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

        if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0)
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am checking condition on onDateSet method so i dont have the date in string to parse in simpleDateFormat.